# AppBarLayout inside ViewPager with scrolling behavior

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

is there a way to put an AppBarLayout inside a ViewPager and get the scrolling behavior working? Background is that I want a header on the first fragment which scrolls out of the screen when the user scrolls down. All other fragments in the ViewPager have no header. My efforts are not successful so far, because the header doesn't scroll. Outside the ViewPager the scrolling workings fine.

I appreciate your help.

Activity layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

            <include layout="@layout/toolbar_shadow"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Fragment layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space_between_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <!-- HEADER -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/header_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <include layout="@layout/journal_header" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
        android:id="@+id/button_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
        app:layout_behavior="de.malnvenshorn.slimly.ui.component.ScrollingBehaviorFAB">

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/button_add_food"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_restaurant_menu_white_24dp"
            fab:fab_size="mini"/>

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/button_add_activity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_directions_bike_white_24dp"
            fab:fab_size="mini"/>

    </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

From Android Document **AppBarLayout**
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html

> This view depends heavily on being used as a direct child within a CoordinatorLayout. If you use AppBarLayout within a different ViewGroup, most of it's functionality will not work.

Try placing your AppBarlLayout in a CoordinatorLayout .